# How to show this splash screen for 3 seconds?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I created my splash screen using the method mentioned here: http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/a/splashscreen.htm

I need to show the splash screen for 3 seconds before showing the main form.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside project file:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  uSplashScreen in 'uSplashScreen.pas' {frmSplashScreen};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;

  frmSplashScreen := TfrmSplashScreen.Create(nil);
  try
    frmSplashScreen.Show;
    // Create your application forms here
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);

    while not frmSplashScreen.Completed do
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    frmSplashScreen.Hide;        
  finally
    frmSplashScreen.Free;
  end;

  Application.Run;
end.
```

Inside splash screen unit:

```
unit uSplashScreen;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmSplashScreen = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    Completed: Boolean;
  end;

var
  frmSplashScreen: TfrmSplashScreen;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmSplashScreen.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OnShow := nil;
  Completed := False;
  Timer1.Interval := 3000; // 3s minimum time to show splash screen
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TfrmSplashScreen.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Completed := True;
end;

end.
```

The splash screen will be visible for minimum time of 3 seconds or more if it will take more time to create all the forms of your application.

Comment: frmSplashScreen is the MainForm so when you free the splash the whole application will close (closing the main form will close the app). Am I wrong?

Comment: frmSplashScreen cannot be the MainForm because is not created through Application.CreateForm

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you want you can follow the method described in the link you provided, and on The splash screen's form code you put a timer which gets fired after 3 seconds and closes the form.

Main .dpr file

```
var SplashScreen : TForm2;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;

  SplashScreen := TForm2.Create(nil); // Creating with nil so this is not registered as main form
  try
    SplashScreen.ShowModal; // Blocking the execution for as long as this form is open
  finally
    SplashScreen .Free;
  end;

  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
```

On the form which will be the 'splash screen' add the timer, enabled at 3000 interval (3s)

with the following event handler

```
procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Close;
end;
```

Comment: SplashScreen is the MainForm so when you close the splash, the whole application will close (closing the main form will close the app). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a timer, whose interval you set to 3000 (3(s) * 1000(ms)). Enabled must be set to true. On the Timer's-default-event you add the code, which is meant to show the main form.