# Delphi splash screen - Timage and Tlabel not being drawn

Tags: image, delphi-7, splash-screen

I'm trying to add a splash screen to a Delphi 7 program. I'm using the example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378605/how-to-show-this-splash-screen-for-3-seconds), except I don't have the 3 second minimum. As soon as the main forms are loaded and ready, I want the splash to close.

The splash form contains a Timage (that is statically loaded with a BMP at design time), and a Tlabel. The form looks correct in the IDE.

When running the program, the background of the splash screen window shows, but neither the Timage or the Tlabel appear on it. It is just an empty rectangle with the color of the form background. It correctly disappears when the main windows shows.
What am I missing?

This is the startup code in program.dpr:

```
  Application.Initialize;

    FormSplash := TFormSplash.Create(nil);

    try
    FormSplash.Show;
    // Create application forms here

    Application.Title := 'Sysex Filer';
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
    Application.CreateForm(TFormKroTimbreCopy, FormKroTimbreCopy);

      // remove the test for timer complete, and just hide the splash when we get here
    FormSplash.Hide;
  finally
    FormSplash.Free;
  end;


  Application.Run;
end.
```

This is the Splash Unit:

```
unit SplashUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TFormSplash = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormSplash: TFormSplash;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormSplash.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OnShow := nil;
{                    // comment out the timer and the completed flag
  Completed := False;
  Timer1.Interval := 3000; // 3s minimum time to show splash screen
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
  }
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I'm not sure if it is the best solution, but it works.
I put

```
FormSplash.Update;
```

in the DPR file right after

```
FormSplash.Show;
```